# Zend Server + Daemontools

Tags: zend-server, upstart, zend

Is anyone running Zend Server under Daemontools?

I know I can use -D NO_DETACH to run apache under daemontools. But, I'm not sure if the other Zend Server components (monitor, lighthttpd, scd, jobqueue) have similar options.

(The end goal is "run Zend Server with service supervision", so upstart would be fine too. For reference, my servers are running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.)

- Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend server (Linux) has a "watchdog" process which starts its daemons in case of failure. So monitor, lighthttpd, scd, jobqueue, java bridge should be protected against crashes.
Apache startup is not changed by Zend as it is part of the Linux distribution.

For example, if you ps for monitor, you will find 2 processes:

```
www-datx  1405     1  0 Jun06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-monitor.ini -u 1001 -g 1001 -s monitor
www-datx  1414  1405  0 Jun06 ?        00:00:09 /usr/local/zend/bin/MonitorNode /usr/local/zend/etc/monitor_node.ini /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d -e
```

The first is the monitor watchdog process and the second is the monitor daemon process.